# How to use COLLECT_SET and group by condition in different columns

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have this table:

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦══════════════╗
║ user_id ║ item_id ║ date_visited ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬══════════════╣
║ 1       ║ 123     ║ 18/5/2017    ║
║ 1       ║ 234     ║ 11/3/2017    ║
║ 2       ║ 345     ║ 18/5/2017    ║
║ 2       ║ 456     ║ 11/3/2017    ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩══════════════╝
```

What I'm trying to achieve (via Hive query) is this result (assuming today is 18/5/2017):

```
╔═════════╦═══════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════╗
║ user_id ║ items_visited_last_5_days ║ items_visited_last_100_days ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════╣
║ 1       ║ 123                       ║ 123, 234                    ║
║ 2       ║ 345                       ║ 345, 456                    ║
╚═════════╩═══════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════╝
```

Basically, I need to group by user_id and generate different columns (based on time intervals) with the user's visits (concatenated item_id). Is it possible to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should use `date` type or at least strings in ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select      user_id
           ,collect_set (case when datediff(current_date,date_visited) <= 5   then item_id end) as items_visited_last_5_days
           ,collect_set (case when datediff(current_date,date_visited) <= 100 then item_id end) as items_visited_last_100_days

from        mytable

group by    user_id
```

---

```
+---------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+
| user_id | items_visited_last_5_days | items_visited_last_100_days |
+---------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+
|       1 | [123]                     | [123,234]                   |
|       2 | [345]                     | [345,456]                   |
+---------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

or

```
select      user_id
           ,concat_ws (',',collect_set (case when datediff(current_date,date_visited) <= 5   then cast (item_id as string) end)) as items_visited_last_5_days
           ,concat_ws (',',collect_set (case when datediff(current_date,date_visited) <= 100 then cast (item_id as string) end)) as items_visited_last_100_days

from        mytable

group by    user_id
```

---

```
+---------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+
| user_id | items_visited_last_5_days | items_visited_last_100_days |
+---------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+
|       1 |                       123 | 123,234                     |
|       2 |                       345 | 345,456                     |
+---------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+
```